# Sum of Random variables in same sleep() time in PYTHON

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-sleep

I want to calculate the sum of numbers if A and B come same time. Can you help me?
My code is here:

```
import threading
import time
import random


def print_hello():
    for i in range(6):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("A :" + str(random.randrange(1,20)) + "\n")


def print_hi():
    for i in range(6):
        time.sleep(1.5)
        print("B :" + str(random.randrange(1,10)))




t1 = threading.Thread(target=print_hello)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=print_hi)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Comment: What is your desired output? Your code runs fine for me but I guess you wnat it to output something different to what its currently doing

Comment: If you're looking to share information between your threads have a look at [this guide](https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/handling-and-sharing-data-between-threads/)

Comment: For example, my output is:

A:6

B:4
A:10

B:1
A:12

if the last two integers come a same time (B:1 and A:12), my output should give me sum of these numbers.

like this "A and B: 13"
I need something like an if conditions. Probably, it is easy but I am a novice on this road. :)

Comment: That sounds very hard actually, hopefully someone with better knowledge of threading or the use of the [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html) will help out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by `if A and B come same time`?

If you want to sum only when the both are at printing numbers on the same second,

```
import time
import random

randomA = 0
randomB = 0
timeA = int(time.time()%60)
timeB = int(time.time()%60)

def print_hello():
    for i in range(6):
        time.sleep(1)
        global timeA
        timeA = int(time.time()%60)
        global randomA
        randomA = random.randrange(1,20)
        print('[A] TimeA',timeA,'TimeB',timeB,' B=',randomB)
        print("A :" + str(randomA))
        if(timeA == timeB):
            print("Times match. Sum = ",str(randomA+randomB))


def print_hi():
    for i in range(6):
        time.sleep(1.5)
        global timeB
        timeB = int(time.time()%60)
        global randomB
        randomB = random.randrange(1,20)
        print('[B] TimeA',timeA,'TimeB',timeB,' A=',randomA)
        print("B :" + str(randomB))
        if(timeA == timeB):
            print("Times match. Sum = ",str(randomA+randomB))



t1 = threading.Thread(target=print_hello)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=print_hi)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Comment: Yes, I wanted to do this. I really thank you.


```
print('[A] TimeA',timeA,'TimeB',timeB, "\n", ' B=',randomB)
```
What is the changes the values ​​of 'timeA' and 'timeB' each time the program is run.

Comment: Great!. There are better implementations of this solution. You can try something related to thread  [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-communicating-between-threads-set-1/)